# date.getTime() is shorter than System.getCurrentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, date, time

I'm trying to create a simple Alarm Clock, but I stumbled upon a problem that I can't seem to fix. I'm trying to parse a string to a date so I can get the difference between the current time and the time to set off the alarm.

Here's my code to parse the time:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(getTimezone());

Date date = sdf.parse(args[0]);
```

Here's my getTimezone() method:

```
public static TimeZone getTimezone() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long milliDiff = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);

    String [] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    String name = null;
    for (String id : ids) {
      TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
      if (tz.getRawOffset() == milliDiff) {
        // Found a match.
        name = id;
        break;
      }
    }
    return TimeZone.getTimeZone(name);
}
```

And here's my code for figuring out the difference:

```
long diff = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

So my problem is that the date.getTime() returns 79680000, while System.currentTimeMillis() returns 1473538047978 (This is of course different every time, but for some odd reason, date.getTime() is not).

Which means that I get a negative number when trying to figure out the difference, and therefore I cannot use it.

EDIT: After a little bit of debugging, I realised that it has to do with the year, month and day not being set, however I do not know how to get those.

Comment: I dont get your problem, the higher number means that it is "newer". You should do a "< 0" check with the result and in the case it is negative multiply it with -1 to turn it around. However please explain you're problem in a more detailed way.

Comment: @Luftbaum What details do you need? I can tell you that the input time is 22:20:00

Comment: Of the current day? Actually, could you tell, what you want to achive in general?

Comment: You need to parse the year, mounth and day too. If you want the current day, create a date for it and add your time to it.

Comment: From the docs - (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition) ' For example, the year value of the parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given from the parsing operation. The TimeZone value may be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and the time zone value in text. Any TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations'

Comment: If you're using Java 8, save yourself most of this headache by using the new java.time library.  As for your current problem.... You're parsing a date, so it's going to be the same thing until you change the value passed in.  It's also using the default values for year/month/day (that is, 1970-01-01), since your format string didn't specify them.

Comment: Thanks @kaetzacoatl I parsed the year, month and day, works like a charm now, thanks again!

Comment: Is your `getTimezone` method designed to obtain the default timezone of the machine?  DateFormat objects already use the default timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did notice that date.getTime() returns 79680000 which is 22 hours and 20 minutes after **1 January 1970**. The problem is (as you noticed) that you did not parse year, month and day.

You can do it by:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
```

Example input `20/04/2016 20:20:0` returns time as `Mon Jan 04 20:20:00 CET 2016` (don't look at the timezone). It is 1451935200000 miliseconds after 1 January 1970.

Note: change string to match your format requirements (the syntax is self-explanatory).

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer by Ronin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430366/642706) is correct. You are trying to put a time-of-day value into a date-time type.

## java.time

Also, you are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

For a time-of-day value without a date and without a time zone, use `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime alarmTime = LocalTime.parse( "12:34" );
```

Getting current time-of-day requires a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( z );
```

But since we are setting an alarm, we care about the date too.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
ZonedDateTime alarm = null;
if ( now.toLocalTime().isBefore( alarmTime ) ) {
    alarm = ZonedDateTime.of( now.toLocalDate() , alarmTime , z );
} else {. // Else too late for today, so set alarm for tomorrow.
    alarm = ZonedDateTime.of( now.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ) , alarmTime , z );
}
```

To calculate the elapsed time until the alarm, use the Duration class.

```
Duration untilAlarm = Duration.between( now , alarm );
```

You can interrogate the duration for a total number of milliseconds. But know that java.time classes are capable of handling nanoseconds.

```
long millis = untilAlarm.toMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated.**
You are using only time without a date with you date object in code (parses only time). If you add there date to you time, your date should be comparable to your System.getCurrentTimeMillis() call. And if you subtracting current millis from date in the past, you will have negative numbers. I prefer this convertion (date2 is after date1):

```
long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
return TimeUnit.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```